# Error when installing MySQL on windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-7

I am trying to install MySQL Server 5.6 2 on a windows 7 machine but it's failing with below error

```
                1: 
                1: Action 11:00:28: INSTALL.

                1: 1: MySQL Server 5.6 2: {FB2E13E5-05CE-4C27-B645-A6FB7D0AB412} 

                1: Action 11:00:28: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications

                1: Action 11:00:28: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications

                1: Action 11:00:28: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions

                1: Action 11:00:28: ValidateProductID. 

                1: Action 11:00:28: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements

                1: Action 11:00:28: FileCost. Computing space requirements

                1: Action 11:00:28: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements

                1: Could not access network location \Hewlett-Packard\\.

                1: Could not access network location \Hewlett-Packard\\.

                1: 1: MySQL Server 5.6 2: {FB2E13E5-05CE-4C27-B645-A6FB7D0AB412} 3: 3 

                1: 
                1: Final actions.

                1: Install error
```

any ideas how can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: `1: Could not access network location \Hewlett-Packard\\.`

Comment: why its trying to access the network location?

Comment: You should check the install instructions or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html

Comment: I've found this solution  This is probably cruft left behind by the HP OEM imaging process. To fix it, go into regedit and look in the registry under these two keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

If you see an "InstallLocation" value containing \Hewlett-Packard\\ just delete it. Then the software should be OK.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/aedd0f90-5779-45e1-85fb-f71cb12166fc/mysql-install-error-on-new-computer-windows-7-professional?forum=w7itproappcompat

Comment: Add @Muhammad Opinion , if you cannot delete it , you need to open registry with Administrator permission.